# jQuery Locating Element Several Levels Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, tree

I am attempting to locate an input field using the following:

```
parent = $(this).parent().parent().$('input[type="text"]').attr('id');
```

However, my script appears to be crashing whenever this runs. Basically, I have a tree of input fields within nested using `<ul>`'s and `<li>`'s, and I am trying to access the parent input field of $(this). Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably missing the `find` function:

```
parent = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]').attr('id');
```

Maybe this can simplify your code:

```
parent = $(this).closest('li').find('input[type="text"]').attr('id');
```

Comment: Works like a charm. The second half didn't do it, but the first half did. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanaelShermett. the second depends on what is the parent of the parent of `this`, if it's not `li` change it to what it is. (`ul`?)

Comment: The parent is an `<li>`, the parent of THAT is a `<ul>`, the parent of that `<ul>` is ANOTHER `<li>`, and inside that is the `<input>` field I was trying to access. :) I ended up needing to add another .parent() too. Sorry if my explanation wasn't clear! I'll work on that for next time!

Comment: @NathanaelShermett. Then you can try this selector:  `$(this).closest('ul:has("input")').find('input[type="text"]').attr('id');`

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for your statement is incredibly wrong =D

It sounds like you are looking for the `find` function:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]').attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent().parent().$('input[type="text"]').attr('id');` is not valid

one possible solution may be

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parent = $(this).parents('#parentElementID').find('input[type="text"]')[0].id;
```

Where #parentElementID is the closest parent of the input targeted.

Comment: Going a bit too fast there. Changed it!

Comment: Now it's inefficient code... :( You should have used `closest` like I did. `parents` going up the root of the DOM. Please read the docs.